# How can I update the linux aging information on group level

Tags: linux, configuration, change-password

We can use the chage command to update the PASS_MAX_DAYS(maximun number of days a password may be used) of a  user.
Does linux provide some command or solution to manage this on group level?
For example, The PASS_MAX_DAYS of group user is 30 days. This means all the users in user group should change their password in 30 days?

Comment: Not programming related. Better suited for [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for member in `groupmems  -g YOUR_GROUP_NAME --list`;do chage -M 30 $member ;done
```

Comment: Thanks. I write a script like that. But I receive a comment that the solution is not good. Does linux provide a direct command or config file to finish it? BTW, I grep the groups file and password file to list all the groupmembers, I saw you use groupmems  -g, but I can not find this command. Is this command name correct?

Comment: It's correct but I'm on Fedora and groupmems may not be a standard command. I don't know a direct command for doing this.